# html5 how to play a Server disk video，and how to programming java code?

Tags: java, html, video

java code

```
@RequestMapping('/getVideo')
 public void loadVideo(HttpServletHttp req, HttpServletResponse response) throws {
Integer id = request.getParameter("fileId"); 
String path = resourceService.getFilePath(id);
File file = new File(path);    
/**how to deal with video for  Output stream to html5 tag video play*/
```

}

jsp code

```
<video src="getVideo.do?fileId=xxxx" type="video/mp4">
```

[process graph](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxuTFZnuf4-bYVBEZmszSnY0VXc/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1)

how to programming, or other idea?

Comment: I don't think HTML 5 video tag is any different to any other mechanism to download your video in this regard. Just start reading the file and output the bytes to your servlet response. Haven't tried, though.

Comment: thanks!I had tried. the viedo can play but that leads to throw a exception and couldn't play again. otherwise couldn't drag the Progress Bar.